# Media screen font resize in bootstrap 4 does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

When I try to set the font size and then the screen size switches to mobile phone(320px) with media screen in my custom CSS. The value still is the value on non media-screen but does not work.

My CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
 .card{

}

.card  .title{
 color:black;
 border-bottom:1px solid #f5f5f5;
 margin-bottom:2px;
}

.card  .title a{
font-weight: bold;font-size: 10px;color:#949393;
 
} }

.card  .title a{

 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 color:#949393;
 
}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the declaration of the normal style is placed after the definition with the media query. Although the media query style is being applied, it is also being overridden with the normal style which is placed further down the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed code

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .card{

}

.card  .title{
    color:black;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f5f5f5;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

.card  .title a{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 10px;
color:#949393;  
} 
}
```